# Один request для post и patch метода в Laravel

Tags: laravel

Всем привет.

Можно ли использовать один свой Request с валидацией для Post и Patch методов?

При добавлении поста нужно обязательно загрузить изображение, о чем валидация и говорит что типа поле image `required`

При обновлении поста, использую тот же Request, но при обновлении могут например изменить заголовок, но изображение менять не будут. Соответственно Request видит что поле image null и валидация не проходит.

Пока на ум приходит только создание отдельного request для обновления, но может есть другой выход?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте отдельный `FormRequest` для обновления. Стандартная команда Laravel тоже так делает:

```sh
php artisan make:model Post --requests
```

---

Единственная проблема такого подхода — дублирование кода. Вы можете устранить его, если вынесете правила проверки всех изображений в отдельный `trait`, который затем включите в оба класса:

```php
trait Image
{
    public function image_rules(): array
    {
        return ['image' => ['image']];
    }
}
```

```php
class StorePostRequest extends FormRequest
{
    use Image;

    public function rules(): array
    {
        $image_rules = $this->image_rules();
        $image_rules['image'] = array_merge(['required'], $image_rules['image']);

        return $image_rules;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделаю